# How can I breathe more comfortably when sitting?

Tags: meditation-practicalities, meditation-recommendation

When I am lying down, my abdomin fills easily, but when sitting with what I believe is proper posture, it feels like my diaphragm is stuck and my breath cannot expand into my abdomen. Only my ribs and upper chest expand. It is not caused by anxiety, nor does it cause a lot of anxiety, but is very distracting and uncomfortable.
It this normal or is it something I can improve with exercises?

Comment: can you perhaps describe your posture? what you are sitting on and exactly how.

Answer (score 1):

yes, breathing will become more comfortable with better diet and exercise.
But even people with very healthy diet and exercise regimen with superfically muscular and visual appearance of "fitness" can have the breathing problems you describe, and those deeper problems take internal energy work to dissolve those blockages.
And if you're serious about doing that, that requires celibacy, lots of quiet meditation with minimal thinking, whether in sitting or standing or walking meditation. Whether qigong, taiji, quiet standing or sitting meditation will all help dissolve the deeper energy blockages that can obstruct smooth breathing.
Celibacy, and ceasing energetically expensive activities such as indulging in food, wine, partying, talking, singing, sexual activity, video games, etc., and instead spending 4-6 hours a day meditating you will definitely experience big improvement in a few months, if not weeks.

Answer (score 1):

Sit with Proper Posture:

Keep your feet flat on the floor, hip-width apart.
Maintain a neutral spine by sitting back in the chair with your back straight and shoulders relaxed.
Ensure that your knees are at or slightly below hip level.
Adjust Your Chair:

Use a chair that supports the natural curve of your spine.
Adjust the chair height so that your feet are flat on the floor and your knees are at a 90-degree angle.
Take Breaks:

Stand up and stretch or walk around every 30 minutes to prevent stiffness and improve circulation.
Mindful Breathing:

Practice deep belly breathing to engage your diaphragm. Inhale slowly through your nose, allowing your belly to expand, and exhale through your mouth.
Focus on slow, controlled breaths to calm your nervous system.
Use a Lumbar Support:

Place a small cushion or a rolled-up towel behind the small of your back to support the natural curve of your spine.
Eye Level:

Position your computer or work at eye level to avoid straining your neck and shoulders.
Keep Hydrated:

Drink enough water to stay hydrated, as proper hydration supports overall comfort and well-being.
Move and Stretch:

Perform gentle stretches to release tension in your neck, shoulders, and back. Simple neck rolls, shoulder shrugs, and seated twists can be beneficial.
Ergonomic Accessories:

Consider using ergonomic accessories such as a footrest, ergonomic chair, or keyboard and mouse to support a comfortable working environment.
Mind-Body Practices:

Incorporate mind-body practices like yoga or mindfulness meditation into your routine. These practices can help reduce stress and improve overall well-being.

Remember that finding the right combination of these tips may require some experimentation. Listen to your body and make adjustments accordingly. If you experience persistent discomfort, consider consulting with a healthcare professional or an ergonomics specialist for personalized advice.

Answer (score 0):

change the pattern of breathing. First make it effortful breathing and then let it be natural. and repeat this.

Step 1: fill your body with more oxygen. by doing some fast breathing.pranayam. etc. particularly forceful belly breathing.

This will enable you to stay breathless for some time.

step2 : Exhal and stop effortful inhalation.As if you are about to be breahtless. and see how your body response. While doing this keep your focus on abdomen only.

Keep repeating for some time. this may help.

Its not normal in a sense that there should not be any kind of tightness in body. So wherever there is tension in body. you must pay more gentle and loving attention to relax those muscles. and every time  you need different strategy. but all the time you need love and  patience. because that is also emotional.

You need to also work at level of mind. there must be some truma,fear etc stored there. and hence real relaxation will be felt by you as mental relief too.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to breathing comfortably while sitting, there are several techniques and positions you can try to enhance your breathing efficiency. Let’s explore some helpful tips:

Use the Nose for Breathing:
Breathing through your nose can slow down your breath and make your lungs work more efficiently.
It also allows the intake of nitric oxide, which aids in oxygen transportation throughout the body.
Breathing through the nose helps filter toxins, allergens, warms cold air, and humidifies dry air.
However, if you’re exercising or have sinus congestion, breathing through the mouth may be necessary.
Practice Belly Breathing (Diaphragmatic Breathing):
The most efficient way to breathe is by bringing the air down toward your belly.
Here’s how to do it:
Sit comfortably or lie down on your back.
Place one hand on your upper chest and the other hand on your belly.
Breathe in slowly, allowing your belly to expand as you fill your lungs completely.
As you inhale, focus on expanding your abdomen rather than just your chest.
Sitting Positions to Improve Breathing:
Try these sitting positions to reduce shortness of breath:
Sitting Position A:
Sit in a chair or a comfortable position.
Keep your feet flat on the floor.
Lean your chest forward slightly.
Rest your elbows on your knees (or place your chin in your hands if comfortable).
Relax your neck and shoulders as much as possible.
Practice your breathing techniques.
Sitting Position B (if a pillow is available):
Place a pillow on a table.
Sit in a chair at the table.
Keep your feet flat on the floor.
Lean your chest forward.
Place your arms on the table.
Rest your head on your forearms (or use a pillow if available).
Continue practicing your breathing techniques.
Standing Positions for Better Breathing:
Sometimes shortness of breath occurs suddenly. If sitting isn’t an option, try standing positions:
Standing Position A:
Find a sturdy wall.
Stand with your feet shoulder-width apart.
Lean your hips against the wall.
Let your hands rest on your thighs.
Allow your shoulders to relax.
Lean forward slightly.
Let your arms dangle in front of you.
Remember to practice your breathing techniques.
Standing Position B:
Find a strong piece of furniture (just below shoulder height, like a table).
Stand at the furniture.
Place your elbows or hands on the chosen furniture.
Lean forward a little.
Relax your neck and shoulders.
You can rest your head on your forearms if your elbows are on the furniture.
Utilize your breathing techniques.
Remember that everyone’s body is unique, so it’s essential to find what works best for you. If you continue to experience discomfort, consider consulting a healthcare professional for personalized advice